# Scroll on item inserted in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've made a `RecylcerView` **(A)** composed by `ViewHolder` containing another `RecyclerView` **(B)**.
When an item is inserted/modified (`notifyItemInserted()`/`notifyItemChanged()`) in **B** I want **A** to scroll until the **B** item just inserted/modified appears on screen.

I've got the position of **B** in **A** and with that I get **B** and I retrive the last element, which is the one just inserted. When I call the **findViewHolderForAdapterPosition** I get `NullPointerExeption`.

My code:

```
RecyclerView B = ((MyAdapter.MyViewHolder)A
                    .findfindViewHolderForAdapterPosition(posB))
                    .getRecyclerViewB();
B.scrollToPosition(B.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this method right?

Answer (score 0):

If this position is (far) beyond displayed area it will not have bound `ViewHolder`. Just use `RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(int position)` here.

Like `A.scrollToPosition(positionOfB)`

Comment: With your solution it only scroll untill B appears, I want the element of B to appear

Comment: Just the same: you are in listener for B, right? Then just use B, do not fetch it from A's ViewHolder.

Comment: B is A's viewHolder so I need to fetch it from A

Comment: Anyway A's element that are not visible now do not generally have ViewHolders for them (that's recycling in RecyclerView for). So to see A's element with bound ViewHolder you should scroll A to it first. And then (after ViewHolder is bound to item) you can scroll it.

Comment: I get the null pointer exeption also when I try to get the ViewHolder of B when elements are all on the screen so that's not my problem, anyway if B has too much elements I could have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to achieve the scroll

Answer (score 0):

I use the layout manager on my Recycler view

```
fun setData(listItems: List<ItemDataModel>) {
            customAdapter.clear()
            customAdapter.addAll(listItems)
            (layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager)?.scrollToPositionWithOffset(customAdapter.itemCount - 1, 0)
        }
```

-----Custom Adapter methods ----

```
 fun clear() {
        items.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

fun addAll(items: List<T>) {
        this.items.addAll(items)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(this.items.lastIndex, items.size)
    }
```